# hello i have been been trying to run my flutter project but it keeps giving me this error

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\BaNcE\Desktop\e_learning\flutter-e-learning\android\app\build.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed adding the required `classpath` in project level `build.gradle`.

1. Go to `build.gradle` in `android` folder, not in android/app folder.
2. Paste

   ```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
   ```

   in dependencies scope as:

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
   }
   ```
3. Run the application again.

Comment: i did that and now its showing a new error

Answer (score 0):

i soved that error and now it shows some other error

Running with sound null safety
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51083/aHDAfGyacf4=/ws
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'analytics')
packages/firebase/src/top_level.dart 164:67                                                                                    analytics$
packages/firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart 10:44                                                              new
packages/firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart 17:42                                                              registerWith
web_plugin_registrant.dart 20:24                                                                                               registerPlugins
web_entrypoint.dart 27:24                                                                                                      
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/ui/initialization.dart 73:24                                  
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                _async
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/ui/initialization.dart 71:16                                  
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 398:10  callMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 402:5   dsend
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/app_bootstrap.dart 27:18                       autoStart
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 528:22                                             
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7                                         callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15